# Python text to speech not finishing the sentence

Tags: python, class, pyttsx

So, I'm trying to create a talking engine with `pyttsx` in python3, when I first call the function to say something it works fine, if I call it again, it just says the first word of the sentence and nothing happens.

```
import pyttsx


class Speech(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = pyttsx.init()
        self.engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

    def say_song(self):
        """ Tell user to choose song  """
        self.engine.say("Please choose song. ")
        self.engine.runAndWait()

    def say_alarm(self):
        """ Tell user to set up the alarm  """
        self.engine.say("Please set up the alarm, after the beep.")
        self.engine.runAndWait()

    def beep(self):
        self.engine.say("beep")
        self.engine.runAndWait()

>>> from voices import Speech
>>> s = Speech()
>>> s.say_song()
>>> s.beep()
>>> s.say_alarm()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue with pyttsx:  https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx/issues/45

I would write a helper method on Speech that basically does the setup + say functionality.

```
def init_and_say(self, text):
    self.engine = pyttsx.init()
    self.engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
    self.engine.say(text)
    self.engine.runAndWait()
```

then call it from each of your methods.  e.g.:

```
def say_song(self):
    init_and_say("Please choose song. ")
```

or call it directly:

```
s.init_and_say("Please choose song. ")
```

Comment: It still has the same issue.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Not sure why this answer was accepted in first place.